# How to remove link from an image in a post?

Tags: images, links, customization

When image is being added in a post it is being wrapped with a `<a href></a>`
I want to know which class controls this segment and where I can find a decent doc for this kind of problems because wp docs sucks when it comes to development and I just started working with WordPress and I don't want to dig in a bunch of code just to solve a simple problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Comment: Nah I know that :) The situation is following : I have a filter that wraps every image to a single div so I can make some design tweaks and that filter consists of simple wrap like this : '<div>' . $data . '</div>' but when I reload the page everything gets wrapped with an <a href></a> element and it becomes this : "<a href='theurl'><div>" . $data . "</div></a>" so I am asking how to get rid of that <a> tag. At least could you give me a clue in which .php script it is being rendered cause I don't have time to dig in all those WP core files for this simple thing. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You can get Wordpress to "click here while uploading the image" automatically if you use the Remove Link URL plugin ;)  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/remove-link-url/

Comment: Can't help you with the exact details, but this question will probably help you out http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42679/5424

Answer (score 2):

`Goto Settings->Media->Auto-embeds->Uncheck the box`( When possible, embed the media content from a URL directly onto the page).Hit save and problem solved.This is the Permanent way.:)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about a plugin that effectively "clicks" the none button for you automatically?

Check out "[Remove Link URL](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/remove-link-url/)" which removes the link by default but still allows it to be added back

[screenshot-1.png?r=494378 http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/56/screenshot1vk.png](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/remove-link-url/)