# remove and disable image link in functions.php

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

Is there a way to disable image or thumbnail link URL, as well as remove existing image/thumbnail links in functions.php?

NOT the setting under media as posted in this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21612/how-to-remove-link-from-an-image-in-a-post), please.

Comment: i don`t understand the question ). Could you provide more details..

Comment: if you look at the link, perhaps you can understand better

Answer (score 1):

A little late to this party but it seems the OP wants to (1) prevent these WP Selfies from recurring and (2) remove existing WP Selfies.

Here is a great filter to prevent it from happening in the future: http://andrewnorcross.com/tutorials/stop-hyperlinking-images/.

And I just posted a snippet that removes existing self linking images here: http://cfxdesign.com/remove-existing-self-linking-images-in-wordpress/.

Comment: Did you try the snippet from your second link on the latest wordpress?

Comment: You asked for it and there's the answer. If **you** tried it in the latest WordPress and encountered some issues then feel free to post a more substantive comment here or on the blog ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I know there is some confusion about your question, but if I understand it correctly it seems like it might be a duplicate of [Disable image attachment links](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18044/disable-image-attachment-links/39906) which I just answered with a note about a plugin that solves the functionality of removing links for images.

The plugin is called "[Remove Link URL](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/remove-link-url/)" and it removes the link by default, still allowing it to be added in if you click the button.

[screenshot-1.png?r=494378 http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/56/screenshot1vk.png](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/remove-link-url/)

I believe this fixes the problem you're describing  :)

Comment: This is exactly the link that I included in the original post as NOT THE ONE. Thanks anyway.

Comment: perhaps if you spent a little time better explaining the desired behavior people could give you better answers to your question.

Comment: As said above, I need to disable thumbnail the links on any images or thumbnails inserted into the post using the media manager, not individually like you posted (which is exactly the link I provided above as I marked not that one). This means, disable must be done in functions.php like a filter for any images inserted via media manager. Then also a filter that can remove any existing links inserted via the media manager, which may not be easy to differentiate if using preg_match of the img url. Hopefully you get the picture.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    return "<div class='post-thumbnail'><a href='" . $featured_image_link . "'>" . $featured_image . "</a></div>";
}
```

Open `function.php` file and delete

```
<a href='" . $featured_image_link . "'>" . $featured_image . "</a>
```

from code

Answer (score -1):

If i understand right. You are looking for something like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14817/how-can-i-remove-fields-in-the-attachment-editor). Key word is `attachment_fields_to_edit`

Comment: not exactly it, but this may be good for restricting attachment editor interface. What I need is to remove the attachment links already in the post using functions.php.

Comment: From existing post? I still don't understand want you want. Tell us full story!

Comment: anyone uploading images, if setting was not previously unset for auto-embed, and one did not knowingly check "none" for Link URL, then a link will be generated for each image inserted into post.

Comment: You describe default behaviour of image insertion.

Comment: well, you asked for full story, that's what caused it. There's the link, and that needs to be removed. What you provided and what the link in my original post only covers prior, not after.

Answer (score -2):

There is a feature

> Goto Settings->Media->Auto-embeds->Uncheck the box

according to link you post and i checked it out its working but maybe not found in all versions I'm using 3.2.1

Comment: I've notated above, NOT the setting.